# Spring boot Consider defining a bean of type

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I added a dependency to my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.location.my1</groupId>
    <artifactId>sMyWebservice-module-services</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I couldn't start my webservice because of an exception: `Field myService in com.company.my.webservice.controllers.MyController required a bean of type 'com.company.location.my1.webservice.my.MyService' that could not be found.`

So I changed my springbootapplication to

```
@SpringBootApplication
    (scanBasePackages = {
    "com.company.location.my1", //what I added to my pom
    "com.company.my.webservice" //current parent package, not necessary
    })
public class WebserviceApplication {
```

So I would scan for the package

And use it in `MyController`like this

```
@Autowired
private MyService myService;

@PostMapping
public MyResponse activate(){
   return myService.activate();
}
```

Comment: You mean I have to create a bean in my `@SpringBootApplication`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: It is in a normal spring java 6 application so it's not anotated there is nothing special about that service, might have to duplicate code to be annotated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if `MyService` class is annotated with `@Service` or `@Configuration`.

if `MyService` is not annotated, you can define in `WebserviceApplication` class a method using `@Bean` which will create the instance for you:

```java
@Bean
public MyService myService() {
    return new MyService();
}
```

Comment: So I won't need to use `scanBasePackages` too right?

Comment: You can you scanBasePackages. However, this will work if MyService class is annotated. I prefer to use scanBasePackages but you need to verify the annotations. Using @Bean, you do not need scanBasePackages for MyService package.

Comment: MyService is an interface so I don't have a constructor do I have to return new MyServiceImpl then?

Comment: Seems to work but now my swagger doesn't work anymore
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151638/spring-boot-swagger2-404