# Spring boot swagger2 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am converting an older java 6 SOAP project to java 8 with spring boot and swagger. I used to be able to use swagger before autowiring a service but now I get a white page in browser with errors rapidly appearing in the console of chrome.

[image: errors]

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.yaml

```
server:
port: 30001
```

In the url there is localhost/**null**/swagger so I assume the problem is there somewhere, I changed the context to test and then the error was localhost/test/**null**/swagger..

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.company.location.myprogram"
})
public class WebserviceApplication {
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the context path in your application.yml?

Comment: yes, then the error becomes like this localhost/test/null/swagger